# Why doesn't this PHP email form add the message when sending?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple contact form on my site. It submits successfully, and sends the email to my email address. But there is one issue: Whatever you type in the message section does not get sent; it returns blank when I receive the email.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is.

Here is the site where I have it running:
http://javinladish.com/contact

Here is the code I am using for the message input on the HTML page:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] message" id="message" placeholder="Start writing your message here..."></div>
```

And here is the PHP that gets submitted when you click send:

```
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "javinladish@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name']);
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message']);
$subject = "Email from javinladish.com";

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
```

Is it because I am using a contenteditable div instead of a regular form element?
Does it have something to do with the PHP?

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out.

Comment: When I receive an email, it looks like this:  
Name: Javin Ladish  
E-mail: hello@email.com  
Subject: Email from javinladish.com  

Message: *nothing*

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to check the variable values. Apply it to every variable and see if the expected value matches with the actual one. PS: what is `check_input`?

Comment: Your regex isn't anchored, which means you can put "anything here then valid@email.address.com" and it will be successfully validated.

Answer (score 2):

Your message box is constructed using a `contenteditable` `DIV`, but that won't be submitted with the `POST` data. You need to use a `<TEXTAREA>`, or use some javascript to extract the message and add it to your `POST`.

Here's a rudimentary example of the required Javascript. This is **not** production ready code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>

<div id=messageDiv contenteditable=true>Here's some content</div>

<form onSubmit="sendData();">

<input type=text name=email>
<input type=hidden name=message id=formMessage>
<input type=submit name=submit value='Submit'>
</form>

<script>
// event handler function called when the form is submitted.
// Find the editable DIV, extract the contents. Find a hidden
// field in the form and place the contents in it.
// return true to let the form submit take place.
function sendData() {
    var message = document.getElementById('messageDiv').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('formMessage').value = message;
    return true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Plus,* adding `name="message"` since OP is using `$message = check_input($_POST['message']);`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to add the javascript function to see if this works.

Comment: I know, that's why I said "*Plus*" ;-)

Comment: @MikeW any idea of the javascript I should use extract the message and add it to the POST?

Comment: @javinladish: there is a **free** search engine called "google" available: "google://div contenteditable js post". Most likely you haven't heard of it, as soon as you hesitate trying using it.

Comment: @javinladish Why not just use a `<textarea>`?

Comment: ...for example `<textarea class="validate[required,length[6,300]] message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Start writing your message here..."></textarea>` @javinladish

Comment: @MikeW It messes with the weird CSS formatting I have. Unfortunately, choosing aesthetics over ease of coding. :P

Comment: @javinladish I've added a basic Javascript example. You'll need to polish it a bit for production use.